# get layer date of dot max file via forge viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, 3dsmax

I am currently tring to retrive layer data from forge viewer.
Have tried get it with `viewer.impl.getLayerRoots()` function but not work. The data that I got is sth like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orxAT.png).
The original data is a .max file and layer info is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvZP9.png).
Comparing to [what I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orxAT.png) totally not match so I am wondering what is the solution

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the 3ds Max (*.max) translator does not extract layer information from the max scene file. This is a known limitation.